# How to pass file.py using http.server in command line as parameter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, localhost, httpserver

Consider a simple **server.py**

```
from http.server import CGIHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
PORT = 5005
handler = CGIHTTPRequestHandler
handler.cgi_directories = ['/']  # this is the current directory
server = HTTPServer(('localhost', PORT), handler)
print ('Server is ready at', PORT, 'PORT')
server.serve_forever()
```

If I call this file using `python.exe -u server.py` in *command line* I'll be able to serve a python script in `'/'` main directory.

I could use also `python -m http.server --bind localhost --cgi 5005` directly.

In both cases I need to open in the browser a specific python file, lets say: `http://localhost:5005/myfunction.py`

Is there an alternative to include the file.py using http.server directly in command line?

For example, something equivalent to `micro -p 5005 file.js` according to **micro npm module**?

Comment: Algo for doing it   ,,,   let x = base url of the server and y = x+pythonfile ..  just remove the x part from y  you get the file nam e..

Comment: do you mean redirect just `localhost:5005/` (the root directory) to a file? I am unfarmiliar with what `micro` is so I have no idea what you are actually asking for...

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Yes. redirect `localhost:5005/` to a specific file using command line.

Comment: hmm, I will dig up relevent source code, I do know if there is an `index.html` it will automatically redirect to that.

Answer (score 1):

it seems redirecting to anything other then `index.html` or `index.htm` (or a list of files) is not supported by [the base code](https://github.com/tadhgmister/cpython/blob/master/Lib/http/server.py#L673):

```
    #if <path is a directory>:

        for index in "index.html", "index.htm":
            index = os.path.join(path, index)
            if os.path.exists(index):
                path = index
                break
        else:
            return self.list_directory(path)
```

one solution would be to simply modify the original source so the tuple `("index.html", "index.htm")` points to something that can more easily be altered at runtime. Alternatively you can define your own wrapper that makes the check yourself, basically just copy the whole `def send_head` function and override that loop to just assign `path` to the file you want to redirect to.

Wish I had a solution that doesn't involve rewriting the source code but I can't think of another (sane) solution.

Comment: I think is a great solution. I'll check this alternative. Thanks for your help.